# Correctly detect encoding without any guessing when using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I’m working on improving the character encoding support for a Python IRC bot that retrieves the titles of pages whose URLs are mentioned in a channel.

The current process I’m using is as follows:

1. [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

   ```
   r = requests.get(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': '...' })
   ```
2. [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

   ```
   soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, from_encoding=r.encoding)
   ```
3. `title = soup.title.string.replace('\n', ' ').replace(...)` etc.

Specifying `from_encoding=r.encoding` is a good start, because it allows us to heed the `charset` from the `Content-Type` header when parsing the page.

Where this falls on its face is with pages that specify a `<meta http-equiv … charset=…">` or `<meta charset="…">` instead (or on top) of a `charset` in their `Content-Type` header.

The approaches I currently see from here are as follows:

1. Use [Unicode, Dammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) unconditionally when parsing the page. This is the default, but it seems to be ineffective for any of the pages that I’ve been testing it with.
2. Use [ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) unconditionally before or after parsing the page. I’m not fond of this option, because it basically relies on guesswork for a task for which we (usually) have perfect information.
3. Write code to look for an appropriate `<meta>` tag, try to heed any encodings we find there, then fall back on Requests’ `.encoding`, possibly in combination with the previous option. I find this option ideal, but I’d rather not write this code if it already exists.

TL;DR is there a Right Way™ to make Beautiful Soup correctly heed the character encoding of arbitrary HTML pages on the web, using a similar technique to what browsers use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to prefer encodings declared in documents over those declared in the HTTP headers. UnicodeDammit (used internally by BeautifulSoup) does this the other way around if you just pass it the encoding from the header. You can overcome this by reading declared encodings from the document and passing those to try first. Roughly (untested!):

```
r = requests.get(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': '...' })

is_html = content_type_header.split(';', 1)[0].lower().startswith('text/html')
declared_encoding = UnicodeDammit.find_declared_encoding(r.text, is_html=is_html)

encodings_to_try = [r.encoding]
if declared_encoding is not None:
    encodings_to_try.insert(0, declared_encoding)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, from_encoding=encodings_to_try)

title = soup.title...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the more general module ftfy, the approach that Unicode, Dammit takes is exactly what I’m looking for (see `bs4/dammit.py`). It heeds the information provided by any `<meta>` tags, rather than applying more blind guesswork to the problem.

When `r.text` is used, however, Requests tries to be helpful by automatically decoding pages with the `charset` from their `Content-Type` header, falling back to ISO 8859-1 where it’s not present, but Unicode, Dammit does not touch any markup which is already in a `unicode` string!

The solution I chose was to use `r.content` instead:

1. `r = requests.get(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': '...' })`
2. `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content)`
3. `title = soup.title.string.replace('\n', ' ').replace(...)` etc.

The only drawback that I can see is that pages with only a `charset` from their `Content-Type` will be subject to some guesswork by Unicode, Dammit, because passing `BeautifulSoup` the `from_encoding=r.encoding` argument will override Unicode, Dammit completely.